# Setting CSS style in <p> not working- Codeigniter

Tags: css

This below code is not applying the class mentioned in the p tag in chrome but working in IE, Firefox
`<p class="p_error"><?php print $this->validation->errorValue;?></p>

Here CSS ->
.p_error{
color:red;
text-align:left;
font-size:12px;
}`

Any hint or reason why its not working?
From the chrome output ->using inspect element -> 
**<p class="p_error"></p>

<p>The Treated By field is required.</p>**

Comment: paste the output of php parsing and css class declaration

Comment: Either there is a caching issue, or there is a problem in the CSS you haven't shown us, or there is a problem in the rest of the HTML (which you haven't shown us either).

Comment: Also, you can see style information in Chrome by right clicking the paragraph and selecting Inspect element. See what it says under Styles in the bottom right panel.

Comment: added all the info in the question.

Comment: what you have inside the variable $errorValue

Comment: Just a text as a part of rule "Last_name is required"

Comment: How does this querstion get upvotes? Seriously...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, the system adds a paragraph tag (`<p>`) around each error message shown. You can easily change these delimiters with this code, placed in your controller:

`$this->validation->set_error_delimiters('<div class="error">', '</div>');`

for Ref: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/validation.html>

Answer (score 2):

What does your CSS look like? It should look something like:

```
.p_error {
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the code that PHP script generated:

```
<p class="p_error"><p>The Treated By field is required.</p></p>
```

HTML specification states that:

- P element cannot be inside another P element
- `</P>` tag may be omitted (it is implied)

Those rules mean that you can write something like this:

```
<p>First paragraph
<p>Second paragraph
```

Browser will automatically close the first paragraph (i.e. add`</p>`) before the second `<p>`.

In your case, it means that the error ends up outside of the `p_error` paragraph, as the "inspect element" shows:

```
<p class="p_error"></p>
<p>The Treated By field is required.</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply, `<p>` cannot wrap `<p>`. So the browser will get super confused if you give it `<p><p>content</p></p>`. The options are either to use the built-in wrapper arguments:

```
<?= form_error('lastname_error', '<p class="p_error">', '</p>'); ?>
```

Or to wrap the whole thing in an element that can wrap `<p>`, like `<div>`.

```
<div class="p_error"><?php print $this->validation->lastname_error;?></div>
```

Of course, you'll have to style the `div` instead of the `p`.

Answer (score 1):

By default, the system adds a paragraph tag (`<p>`) around each error message shown. You can easily change these delimiters with this code, placed in your controller:

`$this->validation->set_error_delimiters('<div class="error">', '</div>');`

for Ref: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/validation.html>

Answer (score 0):

my gues is that inside $errorValue you have some other html tags which overload the `<p>` style declaration

Answer (score 0):

when you browse your page, make sure to hold the <kbd>Shift</kbd> button and press refresh.  That way your browser will load up the new CSS (assuming you've added `p_error` since initially loading the page)

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing inside your `<p class="p_error"></p>` so nothing can be displayed. If you want [individual errors](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html#individualerrors) shown, you should use

```
<?php echo form_error('your_field'); ?>
```

and for [styling](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html#errordelimiters)

```
<?php echo form_error('your_field', '<p class="p_error">', '</p>'); ?>
```

Important note: insde your view, `$this` is not working since it needs the a class context in order to work.

Answer (score 0):

One easy way to fix it would be to change your code to this:

**CSS** (no change)

```
.p_error{ color:red; text-align:left; font-size:12px; }
```

**PHP** (change P to DIV)

```
<div class="p_error"><?php print $this->validation->errorValue;?></div>
```